# Group array of objects by common properties

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get the count for only existing week.I want to get the calculation for month wise with week specific.
Now I can get the weekly count of each month.Now I want to display the week only for existing week.Now showing 0.for eg;may have value for week1 and week 2 I want to display only week1 and week 2 count in response for the month may.for july need to display week1 and week3

```js
const response=[
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "Type": "type3",
    "months": "May",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "Type": "type1",
    "months": "Jun",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "Type": "type2",
    "months": "Jun",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "Type": "type1",
    "months": "May",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User1",
    "week": "Week 3",
    "Type": "type2",
    "months": "July",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "Type": "type3",
    "months": "May",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "Type": "type1",
    "months": "Jun",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "Type": "type2",
    "months": "Jun",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "week": "Week 2",
    "Type": "type1",
    "months": "May",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "week": "Week 1",
    "Type": "type2",
    "months": "July",
    "count": 1
  }
];
const WEEKS = ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4"];
const result = response.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    existingObj = acc.find(ele => ele.UserName == obj.UserName && ele.month == obj.months && ele.Type == obj.Type)
    if (existingObj) {
        existingObj.Week1 += WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 0 ? obj.count : 0;
        existingObj.Week2 += WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 1 ? obj.count : 0;
        existingObj.Week3 += WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 2 ? obj.count : 0;
        existingObj.Week4 += WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 3 ? obj.count : 0;
    } else {
        acc.push({
            UserName: obj.UserName,
            month: obj.months,
            Type: obj.Type,
            Week1: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 0 ? obj.count : 0,
            Week2: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 1 ? obj.count : 0,
            Week3: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 2 ? obj.count : 0,
            Week4: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 3 ? obj.count : 0,
        });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

expected as

```
[{"UserName":"user1","month":"May","Type":"Type3","Week1":2,"Week3":3},
          {"UserName":"user2","month":"May","Type":"Type3","Week1":2},
          {"UserName":"user1","month":"May","Type":"Type1","Week2":1},
          {"UserName":"user2","month":"May","Type":"Type1","Week2":1,},
          {"UserName":"user1","month":"Jun","Type":"Type1","Week2":1},
          {"UserName":"user2","month":"Jun","Type":"Type1","Week2":1},
          {"UserName":"user1","month":"Jun","Type":"Type2","Week1":1},
          {"UserName":"user2","month":"Jun","Type":"Type2","Week1":1},
          {"UserName":"user1","month":"Jul","Type":"Type2","Week3":1},
          {"UserName":"user1","month":"Jul","Type":"Type2","Week1":1},
         ]
```

Comment: Desired output would make things much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point was to regroup records in source array by `UserName` and `month` properties, you may build up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) (using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) with composite key (comprised by `UserName` and `month`) and the value of corresponding groupped object, then extract those objects into array with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values):

```js
const src = [{"UserName":"User1","week":"Week 1","Type":"type3","months":"May","count":2},{"UserName":"User1","week":"Week 2","Type":"type1","months":"Jun","count":1},{"UserName":"User1","week":"Week 1","Type":"type2","months":"Jun","count":1},{"UserName":"User1","week":"Week 2","Type":"type1","months":"May","count":1},{"UserName":"User1","week":"Week 3","Type":"type2","months":"July","count":1},{"UserName":"User2","week":"Week 1","Type":"type3","months":"May","count":2},{"UserName":"User2","week":"Week 2","Type":"type1","months":"Jun","count":1},{"UserName":"User2","week":"Week 1","Type":"type2","months":"Jun","count":1},{"UserName":"User2","week":"Week 2","Type":"type1","months":"May","count":1},{"UserName":"User2","week":"Week 1","Type":"type2","months":"July","count":1}],

      result = [...src
        .reduce((r, {UserName, week: w, Type, months, count}) => {
          const key = UserName+"\ud8ff"+months,
                week = w.replace(' ', ''),
                grouppedRecord = r.get(key)
          grouppedRecord ?
          Object.assign(grouppedRecord, {[week]: count}) :
          r.set(key, {UserName, Type, month: months, [week]: count})
          return r
        }, new Map)
        .values()
      ]
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter down for what ever you want and then loop through the whole thing with the filtered as lookup key.

Like filtering all weeks in May. Then use that for further work.

```
var existingWeeks = response.filter(function(obj) {
    return (obj.months === "May") && (obj.User === "User1");
});
```

Comment: above response is dynamic response

Comment: Yes. It is much better and more generic.